# Replacing a value in table based on string value

Tags: .net, angularjs, html

I have a table which must not display date if a string is a certain value (if warning == P) using AngularJS

I'm trying to use ng-if to accomplish this, but this method would add 2 columns, one for the hidden date and one with correct date:

```
<table ng-table="vm.IncidentList" class="table table-hover">
<tr ng-repeat="row in $data">
    <td data-title="'Incident Number'" {{row.IR_ID_NUM}}{{row.warning}}</td>
    <td data-title="'Type'"{{row.type}} </td>
    <!--if warning == p, do not display date-->
    <td ng-if "{{row.warning}} == "P"">---</td>
    <!--if warning !== p,  display date-->
    <td ng-if "{{row.warning}} != "P"" data-title="'Date'" {{row.date | date}}</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: your `ng-if`s are missing the `=`.  `ng-if` does not insert the data into the DOM if the condition matches, where `ng-show` would.  However, without the `=`, you aren't supplying any condition, and both are shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
<td ng-if "row.warning == 'P' ">---</td>
```

You are also missing `>`

here

```
                                 here
                                  |
<td data-title="'Incident Number'" {{row.IR_ID_NUM}}{{row.warning}}</td>
<td data-title="'Type'"{{row.type}} </td>
<td data-title="'Type'"{{row.type}} </td>
```

It should be

```
<td data-title="Incident Number"> {{row.IR_ID_NUM}}{{row.warning}}</td>
<td data-title="Type">{{row.type}} </td>
<td ng-if "row.warning == 'P' ">---</td>
<td ng-if "row.warning != 'P' " data-title="Date"> {{row.date | date}}</td>
```